# SwipeRefreshLayout: Swipe progress animation

Tags: android, listview, android-animation, swiperefreshlayout

I'm quite new to android and I'm exploring the sample code on google website. The code I'm on currently is the SwipeRefreshLayout: http://developer.android.com/samples/SwipeRefreshLayoutBasic/index.html

In the code, we see the SwipeRefreshLayout being executed for a listview, so in other words, if you drag down the list view, the method is triggered and the listview refreshes itself.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/swiperefresh"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
          android:id="@android:id/list"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

What is confusing me is that there is no layout in the code for the progress animation bar that gets displayed at the top of the listview when you drag it down. Do you think that the SwipeRefreshLayout automatically generates a progress animation bar when you drag it down without requiring the user to specify any layout in xml for it?

For example, if one wants to put padding at both ends of the progress animation bar, so that the animation doesn't touch the ends of the screen when you refresh, how would one do it?

The https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout.html doesn't really say anything about it.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You **can't** change the animation.

In `SwipeRefreshLayout` you can't customize much; I believe this is an attempt of Google to get developers stick to common patterns. What you can style are the four colors of the animation, specified with `setColorScheme()`.

`SwipeRefreshLayout` takes care to show its predefined animation at its top for you. This can be when `canChildScrollUp()` returns false and user 'pulls down', or when you set `setRefreshing(true)`. Turn off the animation with `setRefreshing(false)`. Put your logic in the method `onRefreshing()` of the listener. Override `canChildScrollUp()` if you put something that is not a `ListView` in your `SwipeRefreshLayout`. You should be good to go from here.

Comment: Thanks. I think you are right, there's not a lot to customise besides setting the colour of the progress bar. Do you also know whether the SwipeRefreshLayout class automatically actions the notifyDataChanged() method for the listview? The listview gets refreshed automatically after 3 seconds from the user pulling down on it through the mListAdapter.add(cheese) method, however, the notifyDataChanged() method was never called to notify the listview of the changes to its data.

Comment: No, it doesn't. You can check yourself the code, search `SwipeRefreshLayout.java` in your sdk directory. You need to have installed the source code  for the last revision of the support v4 library (rev 19.1.0)

Comment: So I guess the listview is automatically refreshed from when the data is added to the adapter: mListAdapter.add(cheese)?

Comment: What type does mListAdapter have? Anyway, I think you'd be better off asking a new question entirely.

Answer (score 12):

although you can't change it, you can still hide it and then display your own once triggered :-)

```
SwipeRefreshLayout swiperefresh = (SwipeRefreshLayout)root.findViewById(R.id.swiperefresh);
swiperefresh.setOnRefreshListener(this);
swiperefresh.setColorSchemeColors(0,0,0,0);
swiperefresh.setProgressBackgroundColor(android.R.color.transparent);
```

Notes:

- in eclipse you have to add @SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor") to compile this.
- you still need to call setRefreshing(false) at an appropriate point in time else onRefresh doesn't trigger again.

Comment: setProgressBackgroundColor(android.R.color.transparent) was deprecated. Use swiperefresh.setProgressBackgroundColorSchemeResource(android.R.color.transparent); instead

Comment: This no longer works. However, I found out from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45621101/swiperefreshlayout-without-progress-spinner) that updating view's alpha to 0 will do the trick.