# Swipe refresh layout animation android

Tags: android, swiperefreshlayout

I am using eclipse for android development. I used swipeRefreshLayout in my app. My problem is, when I swipe the ring (circle animation) animation is not displayed instead the line horizontal type is displaying but the color what I fixed for swipe that's working fine and also I want to take some distance and time while I am swiping. Please help me how to I show the circle rotate animation on swiping.

```
 <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
                android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:focusable="true" >

                <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                    android:id="@+id/pager"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="8" />
            </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

and please refer the below image

[image]

i want to show like this

Thanks in advance

Comment: What are you using to add the swipeRefreshLayout? Can you paste the layout file with it?

Comment: will you pls refer my edit post just now i edited my question with code and image

Comment: What is your targetSdkVersion?

Comment: target sdk verion is 21

Answer (score 1):

The answer for your question is that you can't do it with the support library. Android will handle which animation to show based on the OS version your app is being executed.

Take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24099755/swiperefreshlayout-swipe-progress-animation):

> SwipeRefreshLayout takes care to show its predefined animation at its top for you

You can try libraries such as [this](https://github.com/OrangeGangsters/SwipyRefreshLayout), but I'd recommend sticking to Google on this one and let the animation be handled by itself.