# SwipeRefreshLayout Without Progress Spinner

Tags: android, progress, swiperefreshlayout

Is it possible to perform `SwipeRefreshLayout` functionality without showing progress spinner all together. Right now its working perfectly fine with its default behavior of pull to refresh shows Progress spinner and `onRefresh()` I hide It. But I want to hide it all together just want to use the pull to refresh functionality but without progress spinner.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

After Done some RnD found a solution that may help others who want to achieve such functionality

```
 try {
        Field f = mSwipeRefreshLayout.getClass().getDeclaredField("mCircleView");
        f.setAccessible(true);
        ImageView img = (ImageView)f.get(mSwipeRefreshLayout);
        img.setAlpha(0.0f);
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException | IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: i am getting "No field mCircleView in class Landroid/support/v4/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout;"

Comment: @jitendrapurohit make sure your refreshLayout is not a child class.. if it is youll have to do the following mSwipeRefreshLayout.getClass().getSuperclass().getDeclaredField("mCircleView");

Answer (score 4):

swipeRefreshLayout.setProgressViewEndTarget(false, 0)

Answer (score 0):

You can send loader away

```
yourSwipeToRefresh?.setProgressViewEndTarget(true, -screenHeight)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't agree with hiding this spinner completely. but untill the loading starts then hiding it.
I have in my layout many in-progress UIs ..
so what I have done:

```
app:refreshing="@{vm.loadingUI1  &amp;&amp; vm.loadingUI2  &amp;&amp; false}">
```

loadingUI1 is LiveData

With this approach you show interactive loading as action only and it will be hidden immediately when loading-process starts with any component

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [Atakan Akar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59578417/17005735)'s answer and to enable future swipe refreshing:

```
// Reduses spinner size to 0
swipeRefreshLayout.setProgressViewEndTarget(false, 0); 
// Turns off layout refreshing status
swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
```

Answer (score -1):

swipe_refresh_layout.setProgressViewOffset(
false,
-200,
-200
)